# Why won't git allow me to merge dev into master due to "Not possible to fast-forward"?

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket

I am using [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) as my repository. A new repository comes with a *master* branch.

So I created a new branch off of that called *dev*.

I do all development off of *dev*.

IE: I create all new task branches from dev, merge them back into dev, and push.

When I'm ready to merge dev back into master through the CLI, git complains with an error of:

```
git checkout master
git merge dev
```

> fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.

If I go to bitbucket and merge using their UI, it is accepted. So I must be doing something obviously wrong on the CLI-front.

Comment: Did you configure `git config --global merge.ff only` ?

Comment: @AndrewC `git config --global merge.ff` yields `only`

Comment: Try `git merge --no-ff dev` then and see if it works